# How to return/receive multiple arguments in Python?

Tags: python, list, iterable

I'm trying to return the set of all possible factorizations of a given integer.

The way I'm approaching this is as follows. An integer can be written as a product of primes, each to some power. I have a function which creates a list containing lists of the primes to their powers.

For example: 1400 = 2^3*5^2*7. So I have a function which produces

```
K = [[[2, 2, 2], [4, 2], [8]], [[5, 5], [25]], [[7]]]
```

It's a list with three elements. I can then produce the set of all factorizations by

```
product([[2, 2, 2], [4, 2], [8]], [[5, 5], [25]], [[7]])
Out:
[([2, 2, 2], [5, 5], [7]),
 ([2, 2, 2], [25], [7]),
 ([4, 2], [5, 5], [7]),
 ([4, 2], [25], [7]),
 ([8], [5, 5], [7]),
 ([8], [25], [7])]
```

where `product` is called from itertools.

The problem is that what I want is to feed `product` the **individual** elements of the list `K` (as if a user had literally written 3 arguments for the function product). But I can't seem to create a function that is capable of doing this in general. In general, I won't know how many arguments I will have to feed `product`. Can this be done? I'm sure I can find a less weird way to do this, but now I'm curious to if this can be done, and if not, why.

Comment: `itertools.product(*K)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
factors = [[2, 2, 2], [4, 2], [8]], [[5, 5], [25]], [[7]]
print(list(product(*factors)))
```

Read about Unpacking Argument Lists in [Python's Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "star" syntax to accept a variable amount of arguments to a function

```
def foo(*args):
    # args is a tuple containing all arguments passed to foo
    print(len(args))
```

Now you can pass as many arguments to `foo` as you like

```
foo(1, 2, 3)  # prints 3
foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)  # prints 6
```